# Failed to start Apache Server after configuring Client Authentication

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, centos7, authentication, httpd

**CentOS 7**  | **Apache 2.4.6**

---

I have built a private Certificate Authority (CA) and two certificates (one for the server and one for a client).

Then, I configured the Apache to use the certificate X.509 in order to answer HTTPS connections, and everything went fine (I saw it in the browser).

Then, when I was configuring the Client Authentication, restarted the server and got the following error:

> Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Now it appears "Syntax OK" but I still can't start the server, getting the following errors, using the commands:

. systemctl status httpd.service

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status httpd.service
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-05-01 18:35:40 WEST; 2min 3s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 12292 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 12288 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 12288 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 01 18:35:37 src_ca systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
May 01 18:35:40 src_ca systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 01 18:35:40 src_ca kill[12292]: kill: cannot find process ""
May 01 18:35:40 src_ca systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 01 18:35:40 src_ca systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
May 01 18:35:40 src_ca systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
May 01 18:35:40 src_ca systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

."journalctl -xe"

```
May 01 18:39:16 src_ca polkitd[2607]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:12474:9099194 (system bus name :1.157 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallba
May 01 18:39:16 src_ca systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit httpd.service has begun starting up.
May 01 18:39:18 src_ca systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 01 18:39:18 src_ca kill[12483]: kill: cannot find process ""
May 01 18:39:18 src_ca systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 01 18:39:18 src_ca systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit httpd.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
May 01 18:39:18 src_ca systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
May 01 18:39:18 src_ca systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
May 01 18:39:18 src_ca polkitd[2607]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:12474:9099194 (system bus name :1.157, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/
```

I'll leave bellow the process that I have used to configure the Client Authentication. I'll leave some useful files at the bottom of the question.

---

**Procedure to configure the Client Authentication**

> 1. Started by locating the option "SSLCACertificateFile" in the file “/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf”: `vi +/SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`
> 2. Updated the path to: `/etc/pki/CA/certs/ca.crt`

This is the location of the certificate for the CA.

To note: The certificate of the client is inside the folder /etc/pki/CA/certs. I am not sure if this causes any problem when configuring the Client Authentication. (**Update: Edit 1**)

> 3. Removed the "#" on the directive "SSLVerifyClient require".
> 4. Saved the changed and exited the file with `:wq` and then restarted the server: `systemctl restart httpd`

---

**Useful Files for debug**

. "etc/hosts" (Adding the IP + Host)

[image: etc/hosts]

. "/etc/hostname" (Can be done with `hostnamectl set-hostname new-hostname`)

[image: /etc/hostname]

. "etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf"

[image: etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf]

. "/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf"

[image: /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf]

. "/var/log/httpd/error_log"

```
[Wed May 01 18:18:13.050768 2019] [core:notice] [pid 11416] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Wed May 01 18:18:13.053282 2019] [suexec:notice] [pid 11416] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[We May 01 18:18:16.238779 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 11416] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /etc/httpd/logs/ssl_error_log for more information
```

. " /var/log/httpd/ssl_error_log"

```
[Wed May 01 18:18:16.238749 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 11416] AH01895: Unable to configure verify locations for client authentication
```

Comment: So did you try doing what the error message told you to do?

Comment: Also, **please** don't paste a picture of the terminal output. Use copy and paste to paste the actual text instead, using the code formatting option.

Comment: @JennyD I just updated the answer. The `ServerName` problem was solved, but I still have problems starting the server. Check the **Edit 3**.

Comment: @JennyD the question is more clean now, thank you for your feedback.

Comment: What have you set `SSLCACertificateFile` to? The post says you edited the setting, but it does not say what you changed it to.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have changed it to `/etc/pki/CA/certs/ca.crt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used a certificate built on another context, restarted Apache, the errors were not showing.

That means the error must be with the certificate.

Given that, I re-watched carefully the procedure that I have used to build the CA (I'll add the procedure at the bottom of this answer) and found the error.

I was using the "temporary" certificate instead of `cacert.pem`.

---

**Procedure to create the CA:**

1. `openssl genrsa -des3 -out /etc/pki/CA/private/cakey.pem`
2. `openssl req -new -key /etc/pki/CA/private/cakey.pem -out /etc/pki/CA/ca.crt`
3. `openssl x509 -req -days 100 -in ca.crt -out cacert.pem -signkey private/cakey.pem`